# How to convert this DataFrame into Json

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have this `DataFrame` with 2 columns

```
print(df)

     a                b

     10          {'A': 'foo', ...}
     20          {'B': 'faa', ...}
     30          {'C': 'fee', ...}
     40          {'D': 'fii', ...}
     50          {'E': 'foo', ...}
```

when I try to convert it into `json` it goes wrong:

```
df.to_json("test.json")

# Output:


{
"a":{10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
"b":{
   "1":{
      "A":"foo",
      ...
      },
   "2":{
      "B":"faa",
      ...
      },
   "3":{
      "B":"faa",
      ...
      },

   ... 

   "5":{
      "E":"foo",
      ...
      }
}
```

I don't even know ehere the numbers come from.

My desired `json`:

```
[{
   'a': 10,
   'b': {
         'A': 'foo', 
         ...
        }, 
    ...
    'a': 50,
    'b': {
         'E': 'foo', 
         ...
        }
}
]
```

Comment: Your desired output is not a valid JSON object.

Comment: And which form would be the closest example to it? PD: why is not a valid format?

Comment: `df.to_json("test.json", orient='records')`?

Comment: I tried that too but still the same output

Comment: not on my side, that would give `[{"a":10, "b":{"A":"foo"} } , {"a":20, "b":{"B":"bar"} }, ....]`.

Comment: well, this is weird. I've just changed the df format and that index remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
data = []
for i in df:
    data.append({'a': df[i[0]], 'b': df(i[1])})
```

This should give you your desired output.

If you want to convert this into a JSON file then you can do the following:

```
with open("myjson.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```